# Why is my React setState is looping forever?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a pomodoro app and the count down clock will keep toggle the `breaking` state when the time is up, the `breaking` state will indicate whether you're currently working (`breaking === false`) or you're taking a break (`breaking === true`).

However, the console shows that the `setBreaking` are keep looping, resulting in error. I've tried to pass in an anonymous function with `prevState => !prevState`, error still occur. Any advice?

Here are the excerpt:

```
  function Clock() {
    const [minute, setMinute] = useState(parseInt(remainingTime/60));
    const [second, setSecond] = useState(padZero(remainingTime%60));
    const [breaking, setBreaking] = useState(false);

    function padZero(num) {
      return num.toString().padStart(2,0);
    }

    function countDown() {
      useInterval(() => {
        setRemainingTime(remainingTime-1);
      }, 1000);
    }

    if (remainingTime === 0) {
      setBreaking(!breaking)              // keep looping 
      setCountDown(false);
      setRemainingTime(breakMinute*60)
    }

    if (countingDown === true) {
      countDown();
    } else {
      console.log('Timer stopped!');
    }

    return <h1>{minute}:{second}</h1>
  };
```

Comment: Hey, just wondering if you're using useInterval the same as [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). The function will be executed every 1000 ms and would probably need to be passed to clearInterval once it should stop.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to put subscriptions, timers... inside the main body. Instead, you need to put your code and start the countdown into a useEffect(..., []) hook.

By not using hooks, your code will be executed everytime you are trying to render the component, and sometimes it's kind of random...

```js
function Clock() {
    const [minute, setMinute] = useState(parseInt(remainingTime/60));
    const [second, setSecond] = useState(padZero(remainingTime%60));
    const [breaking, setBreaking] = useState(false);

    React.useEffect(() => {
      // Your code here
    }, []);

    return <h1>{minute}:{second}</h1>
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution using useEffect

```js
function Clock() {
    const [minute, setMinute] = useState(parseInt(remainingTime/60));
    const [second, setSecond] = useState(padZero(remainingTime%60));
    const [breaking, setBreaking] = useState(false);

    function padZero(num) {
      return num.toString().padStart(2,0);
    }

    function countDown() {
      useInterval(() => {
        setRemainingTime(remainingTime-1);
      }, 1000);
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (remainingTime === 0) {
        setBreaking(!breaking);
        setCountDown(false);
        setRemainingTime(breakMinute*60)
      }
    }, [remainingTime]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (countingDown) {
        countDown();
      } else {
        console.log('Timer stopped!');
      }
    }, [countingDown]);

    return <h1>{minute}:{second}</h1>
  };
```

Using useEffect you can watch the state variable and take action based on that.